# How to save Bit(1) field in postgresql from jpa repository spring boot service

Tags: postgresql, jpa, boolean, save, bit

I have a code that reads and writes into a table, which has a field of bit(1). When I am reading this table hibernate converts this into boolean just fine but when I try to save to it, it gives me column is type bit but expression is type boolean. I cannot change this field to boolean at db aide.

So far I tried seeling @Type, attribute converter and columnDefinition=Bit  but still not working.

Please help

I am trying to save a Boolean value from Java using jpa repo which is  Bit(1) field in postgres SQL db but getting error while doing insert or update.When I am reading this table hibernate converts this into boolean just fine but when I try to save to it, it gives me column is type bit but expression is type boolean. I cannot change this field to boolean at db aide.

Comment: Why use `bit(1)` and not `boolean`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. From question "I cannot change this field to boolean at db aide".

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: that doesn't really answer the question _why_ he insist on using a data type that is not appropriate for the value to be stored and apparently results in problems that could be solved by using the correct data type to begin with.